# Download pdf file from server, save it in ApplicationSupport directory. iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, download, nsurlconnection

I'm newbie in iOS development, and I wanna know how can I download a file from a server, and save it in my Application Support folder. I wanna keep it as .pdf file, to be able to display it in UIWebView.

After long time in diferents websites, I think I should use NSURLConnection (asynchronous) to download it. Or NSData (I tried it already, but it didn't work).

So, there is someone who can help me, by show me a sample code of this?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: What is the original format of the file you are downloading? Is it pdf?

Comment: Yes! And the file exists on the server ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549369/iphone-pdf-download) for an example of how to do it.

This example uses [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is an alternative to `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`. I strongly suggest you to use this framework, which will make your life much easier.

If you are really willing to use `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection`, see [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215095/nsurlconnection-download-large-file-40mb).

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.productListArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *productDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{

     NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

     if(![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:pdfString])
     {
         dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^()
                        {
                            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:120];

                            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                            NSError *connectionError = nil;

                            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                                             error:&connectionError];

                            if(connectionError)
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Pdf Connection Error==>%@",connectionError.userInfo);
                                [AMSharedClass showAlertMessge:@"Request timeout"];

                            }
                            else if ([response.MIMEType isEqualToString:@"application/pdf"])
                            {
                                NSLog(@"pdfFilePathURLString==>%@",pdfString);

                                [data writeToFile:pdfString atomically:YES];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                [AMSharedClass showAlertMessge:@"Pdf not found."];
                                if (idx+1 == [self.productListArray count])
                                {
                                    [self.btnSetting setEnabled:NO];
                                }
                            }
                            if (idx+1 == [self.productListArray count])
                            {
                                [[[AMSharedClass object]sharedHUD]hideOnWindow];
                                self.pdfURLString =  [self joinPDF:self.productFilePathUrlArray WithDetails:self.pdfInfoArray];
                                [self initialConfiguration];
                                NSLog(@"%@",self.productFilePathUrlArray);
                            }
                        });

         // Long running task

     }
     else
     {
         if (idx+1 == [self.productListArray count])
         {
             self.pdfURLString =  [self joinPDF:self.productFilePathUrlArray WithDetails:self.pdfInfoArray];
             [self initialConfiguration];
             NSLog(@"%@",self.productFilePathUrlArray);
             [[[AMSharedClass object]sharedHUD]hideOnWindow];
         }
     }
 }];
```